# Widget html code error

Tags: widgets

When I try to add HTML code to my widget , is shoes an error that tags should be removed.[image][image]

How to solve my problem

Comment: That's not HTML. That's a script.

Answer (score 2):

Changes were made to the Text Widget in WordPress 4.8. The editing experiencing was enhanced in some ways but this also caused issues with certain HTML tags and formatting.

Fortunately, a new [Custom HTML Widget was added in WordPress version 4.8.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/08/01/fixes-to-text-widget-and-introduction-of-custom-html-widget-in-4-8-1/). The Custom HTML Widget allows `<script>` tags, and will not remove certain formatting unlike the new version of the Text Widget:

[image: Custom HTML Widget]